# SQL: how do write the ORDER BY based on value within a group?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table

```
project issues  updated
    1   1   2009-09-03
    1   2   2009-09-08
    2   1   2009-09-12
    2   2   2009-09-01
```

and I would like to sort so that the projects are sorted in descending order so that the project with the latest updated issue is first etc., but all issues of a project are kept together and the issues are in ascending order within the project based on issue number

the result should be:

```
project issues  updated
   2    1   2009-09-12
   2    2   2009-09-01
   1    1   2009-09-03
   1    2   2009-09-08
```

Comment: Add 4 spaces before each line of your table

Comment: BTW, I believe there's a typo on the last line of the first table and `issues` should be 2, but I'm not sure so didn't fix that in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would work (sorry, no mysql at hand, so I just tested on sqlite...):

```
select t.project, t.issues, t.updated from t
join (select project, max(updated) as dat
      from t group by project) as t1
  on (t.project = t1.project)
order by t1.dat desc, t.issues asc
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the job:

```
SELECT mt.* 
FROM mytable mt
 JOIN (SELECT MAX(updated) AS LastUpdated, project 
               FROM mytable GROUP BY project) lu ON lu.project = mt.project
ORDER BY lu.LastUpdated DESC, mt.Issues
```

Oops, I just saw the MySQL tag.  I don't know if this solution will work in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.project, p.issues, p.updated, max(r.updated)
FROM table p INNER JOIN table r ON r.project=p.project
GROUP BY p.project, p.issues, p.updated
ORDER BY 4 DESC, p.project, p.issues
```

I've tried an equivalent query in mysql & it looks like it works the way you want it to.

Comment: Thanks it works. Although the issues are now in reverse sequence within each project. What would I change to keep the issues in numeric sequence?